# Rails model create function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, attributes, routes

I used the nested model gem to create a Picture that can take tags. Now I have added an attribute to my model Picture so it has an attribute taglist. When I create a new tag, I want this to happen

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @tag = Tag.new(params[:id])
    if @tag.save
      taglist = picture.taglist
      taglist+=@tag.tagcontent
      @tag.picture.update_attributes(:taglist => taglist)
    end
  end
end
```

and in my routes

```
resources :pictures do
   resources :tags
end
```

When i make a new tag, nothing happens in the taglist attribute, like nothing happened, why?

Comment: is picture defined? What errors are you getting?

Comment: @Stephanie yes its defined (ive associated them), no errors show, just nothing happens

Comment: Um, are you sure about that `params[:id]`? Shouldn't that be `params[:tag]`?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to help due to lack of information, but I see two possible issues:

1. `Tag.new(params[:id])` doesn't make sense. Assuming Tag inherits from ActiveRecord::Base, you need to pass it a hash of attributes (e.g. `Tag.new(:name => 'mytag')`) You are likely not getting into the `if @tag.save` block at all due to validation errors. Also, you don't need to provide an id to an object you want to create. The database chooses the id.
2. Inside the block, `picture` is undefined on the first line.

Why not try debugging with something like:

```
if @tag.save
  taglist = picture.taglist
  taglist+=@tag.tagcontent
  @tag.picture.update_attributes(:taglist => taglist)
else
  p "ERRORS:"
  p @tag.errors.full_messages
end
```

See what errors that prints out into your console.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely think that picture is probably undefined in the `create` method of the controller. Can you show us the view, the form you're using to create a new tag? Is there a form field through which you're choosing which photo gets the tag?

Please show us the association and your view for creating the new tag.

Actually, what I'd really recommend instead of cooking up your own is to use:

Agile Web Development's **[acts_as_taggable_on_steroids](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/acts_as_taggable_on_steroids)**

It's an excellent plugin to make tagging easy; it has quite a few nifty features built in, including the searches, tag clouds, etc. We use it on our projects.